# Remove parent node if childnode has a specific attribute

Tags: xslt

This is in connection with my previous question, but now the goal is different. Considering below xml file:

```
<project>
    <UserProjAttr>G</UserProjAttr>
</project>
<mainpart>
    <proxy>
        <singlepart>
            <part>
                <coating>SP</coating>
            </part>
        </singlepart>
        <singlepart>
            <part>
                <coating>G</coating>
            </part>
        </singlepart>
        <singlepart>
            <part>
                <coating>G</coating>
            </part>
        </singlepart>
    </proxy>
</mainpart>
```

The number of singpart node is dynamic; but I need to check all //mainpart/proxy/singlepart/part/coating node value is same as //project/UserProjAttr value, if there is difference then the whole mainpart node can be skip for copying.

Below is my code, but surely this is problematic due to my inexperience with xslt.

```
<xsl:variable name="finish" select="/project/UserProjAttr"/>
<xsl:template match="proxy">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$currfinish = 'false'">
    </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="currfinish" >
    <xsl:for-each select="@*|singlepart" >
        <xsl:if test="not(@*|singlepart[part/coating/@key = $finish])" >
            <xsl:value-of select="false()" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Do note your XML is not well-formed, as it does not have a single root element. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @TimC, I'm not totally aware. I deleted some details on my xml file to highlight the important info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just planning on removing nodes, and leaving other nodes unchanged, it is always good to start with the identity template as this takes care of copying the things you need.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means you just need a template to ignore `mainpart` if all of the descendant `coating` elements do match `UserProjAttr`. Or rather, if there is not a descendant `coating` that does not match  `UserProjAttr`

```
<xsl:template match="mainpart[not(proxy/singlepart/part/coating != //project/UserProjAttr)]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mainpart[not(proxy/singlepart/part/coating != //project/UserProjAttr)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you were using XSLT 2.0, you could use a variable in the template match if you felt it made it more readable

```
<xsl:variable name="finish" select="//project/UserProjAttr"/>

<xsl:template match="mainpart[not(proxy/singlepart/part/coating != $finish)]" />
```

And in XSLT 3.0, you can replace the identity template with a single line...

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, would it handle the loop to check each singlepart/part/coating node?

Comment: Expressions that check node-sets, like `proxy/singlepart/part/coating != //project/UserProjAtt`, will check every node in each set, and return true if at least one pair of nodes satisfies the condition. So, you don't need the loop at all. See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWH

Comment: Thanks Tim, that was awesome. Thank you also for sharing that website, it will truly help a lot.